Finding all integers $(a,b,c)$ such that $\sqrt{ab} + \sqrt{bc} + \sqrt{ca} = abc + 1$
Find all integers $(a,b,c)$ such that
$\sqrt{ab} + \sqrt{bc} + \sqrt{ca} = abc + 1$
Attempts
To solve the equation
$\sqrt{ab} + \sqrt{bc} + \sqrt{ca} = abc + 1$,
Since the equation involves square roots and products, large values of $a$, $b$, and $c$ would likely make the left and right sides differ significantly. So I focused on small values for $a$, $b$, and $c$.
I checked simple cases such as $a = b = c = 1$, $a = b = c = 0$, $a = 1$, $b = 1$, $c = 0$, and a few other small integers to see if they satisfied the equation. This led to finding some permutations of $0$,$1$ and $-1$ which are solutions. They are
$(-1,0,-1)$,$(0-1,-1)$,$(0,1,1)$,$(1,1,0)$,$(-1,-1,0)$,$(1,1,0)$,$(1,0,1)$
My question is do any more solutions exist or how can we find the family of solution pairs satisfying this equation

Hint: Show that $ (a, b, c) = \pm (x^2, y^2, z^2 )$ or $ \pm ( x^2k, y^2k, z^2k)$. $\quad$ Yes, there are other solutions, like $(1, 1, 4)$.

Intuitively we can tell $abc+1$ should be much larger than $\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ca}$ for large values of $a, b, c$, as you noticed. Here is one way how to prove this. We are supposing $a, b, c>0$.
First, here is one simple lemma.

Lemma. Let $x, y$ be real numbers.

If $x, y\ge 1$, then $xy+1\ge x+y$
If $x, y\ge 2$, then $xy\ge x+y$.


Proof.

If $x, y\ge 1$, then $(x-1)(y-1)\ge 0\implies xy+1\ge x+y$.
If $x, y\ge 2$, then $(x-1)(y-1)\ge 1\implies xy\ge x+y$.

The second case of this lemma can be easily extended to more variables: if $x, y, z\ge 2$, then
$$x+y+z\le xy+z\le xyz.$$
This means, if $a, b, c\ge 2$, by combining our lemma with the rearrangement inequality, we get
$$\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ca}\le a+b+c\le abc < abc+1$$
which is a contradiction. Thus one of our variables, say $c$, must be equal to $1$, and the equation becomes
$$\begin{aligned}
\sqrt a+\sqrt b+\sqrt{ab} &= ab+1
\end{aligned}$$
Of course $\sqrt a, \sqrt b\ge 1$, so, by our lemma
$$\begin{aligned}
\sqrt a+\sqrt b+\sqrt{ab} &\le 2\sqrt{ab}+1\implies\\
ab &\le 2\sqrt{ab}\implies\\
ab &\le 4
\end{aligned}$$
There are not many cases to check and its easy to see $a, b = 1, 4$ is the only solution.
If one of our variables is negative, then one other must be zero, or else we'll be delving into complex number territory. Also, it is easy to solve the case where one of the variables is zero.

Note that you could have all 3 variables negative, without delving into complex number territory. In this case, since $ 0 \geq abc+1 \geq 0$, we know that at best we have to consider $(-1, -1, -1)$ which isn't a solution. $\quad$ As an aside, for lemma 2, $ (x-1)(y-1) \geq 1$ gives it directly. (similar to your lemma 1).

@CalvinLin thanks for the suggestion, I've updated the lemma!
With respect to the case where all variables are negative, notice this would make the $RHS$ of the equation at most $0$, so you would need a variable to be equal to zero anyway.
